# Julia - Adding elements to a list of a certain type

Tags: julia

Is there a way to add to a list of arbitrary type, a new element of that type, automatically

My problem is, I have a dictionary, with some keys and every value is an array, and all the arrays are of the same length

```
a = Dict
    x = [1,2,3]
    y = ["a", "b", "c"]
    z = [Dict(filled with stuff), Dict(also filled), Dict(filled)]
```

The problem is, I need to add to every single element of `a` with something *neutral*, fx I would need to do one round of *filling* which would result in

```
a = Dict
    x = [1,2,3,0]
    y = ["a", "b", "c", " "]
    z = [Dict(filled with stuff), Dict(also filled), Dict(filled), Dict()]
```

but `a` wont always be structured like this, `x`, `y` and `z` may just as easily all be arrays of integers, floats, or whatever mix imaginable

**tl;dr** can I `push!()` to an array in some automatic way a *basic* element of the type that the array holds? so that if array is defined as `Array{T}` I can automatically append type `T` ?

**brief explanation**

I have files that include some standard variables that are always present, but there will also be additional data, but this additional data varies, but what they do have in common, is that all the variables can be grouped into lengths, some variables will be arrays of length 95, some will be of length 72 etc, and that is how they are grouped. All the additional arrays will be put inside a dictionary, but if data is added, I want the dictionary to be automatically expanded so the lengths still match

Comment: maybe I'm just being a bit slow today, but I'm still not clear what you want to happen. Do you mind providing a 'pseudocode' example of what you would like to happen?

Comment: Hi @TasosPapastylianou I have a dictionary whose values are always arrays, but the type of arrays is always unknows, some arrays may have strings, others floats etc, I'd like to push!() to every array in the dictionary, a single element with a neutral element, i.e empty string, 0.0 etc
Dont waste your time though as I solved it (crudely) by just converting the arrays to Array{Any} and push an empty string to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not clear what the neutral value of a type is. Therefore, you will have to define your own function for each type, e.g, like you proposed for `String`s:

```
neutral(::Type{String}) = " "
```

For `Number`s, you can use the built in `zero` function:

```
neutral{T<:Number}(::Type{T}) = zero(T)
```

The neutral element for a `Dict` is a bit more complicated:

```
neutral{T<:Dict}(::Type{T}) = T()
neutral{V}(::Type{Dict{TypeVar(:K),V}}) = Dict{Any, V}()
neutral{K}(::Type{Dict{K}}) = Dict{K, Any}()
```

As a fallback, you can still use the empty string as in your comment:

```
neutral(x) = ""
```

Finally, you can define a function to push the neutral element to an array:

```
push_neutral!{T}(a::AbstractArray{T}) = push!(a, neutral(T))
```

For example:

```
push_neutral!([Dict(1=>2), Dict("1"=>2)])
3-element Array{Dict{K,Int64},1}:
 Dict(1=>2)       
 Dict("1"=>2)     
 Dict{Any,Int64}()
```

This also demonstrates the need for the three different methods for `Dict`. Because of the mixed types shown by the parameter `K`, only this first of the three definitions is not sufficient.

Edit: Applying this function to your `Dict` `a` holding all the `Array`s can be simply done by:

```
foreach(push_neutral!, values(a))
```

Edit2: The specialized version

```
neutral{K, V}(::Type{Dict{K, V}}) = Dict{K, V}()
```

seems to be unnecessary.

Edit3: A `NullableArray` is probably a better solution to your problem. However, it is still a bit difficult to work with in the current version.

Comment: as there is no "elegant" way to achieve this Ill stick to the "Any" array as I dont think I can forsee every possible type there may be, although string, float and Dict() is the most common, there may surface some odd type that would pulverize everything, so better safe than sorry, but thanks anyway for taking the time to write up that answer